Drainage area at a point of my choice
I want to get drainage areas at specific points (the points are places I want to put culverts for a railwork construction).
The thing is that when I run either upslope area or PCraster tools, the drainage area I get many times gives me a pixel as an output which happens probably due to the fact that the tool doesnt seem to recognize any stream there.
From what I understand, if the point I want to select doesnt overlap with the river the tool gives me (tool like SAGA channel network and drainage basins), then the output result is a single pixel.
What I want is to click at any point of the DEM and get the drainage area of this point. Is there any way to do it?
